# Sublime linter node 14 error circular dependency

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I recently installed node v14 and my linter on sublimeText is KO.

On every file focus it open a kind of console with this inside:

```
SublimeLinter: #2 eslint file.vue ERROR:
====================================================

(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cat' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'chmod' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cp' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'dirs' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pushd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'popd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'echo' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tempdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pwd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'exec' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ls' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'find' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'grep' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'head' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ln' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mkdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'rm' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mv' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sed' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'set' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sort' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tail' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'test' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'to' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'toEnd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'touch' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'uniq' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:72116) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'which' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

> Please stack overflow members, you are my only hope.

Answer (score 0):

By default, SublimeLint uses global installation of eslint. So most likely the installation is outdated and can be updated to fix the issue. At least it worked for me.